# Friend Module using PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a web application in which I have members and I want to add a friends system to this application.

Please help me out with any tutorials or guidelines.

The aim is to say user a and user b are in the system and if user a logs in he should see an *add as a friend* button; on clicking the button it should display all the users in the system to him and ask if user a would like to to add them as friends and when the friend request is sent and the corresponding user accepts it he should be shown in the user a's friend list.

Comment: is not the English is the logic.

Comment: yep please guide me with the logic

Comment: Select all friends where their systems are equal and develop a view with add as friend buttons accordingly.. not doing your work for you, that is the theoretical solution. God help you if you couldn't think of that on your own. Also create a friends table containing PKs of friendly users.

Comment: You want to create a facebook alike functionality?

Comment: the problem is how do i come know user a is a friend of user b ?

Comment: @ Dee Jay Yes do u know anything relevant

Comment: Make a table of friends and select all friends of the user X

Comment: what you want that complete code is written by any other community member for you and you just copy and paste that .why you not hire any one for this ?

Comment: @ rahul m myself an intern learning php and in way to complete my project

Answer (score 2):

There's no tutorial for such functionality. It's called knowledge.

I'm not going to give you the complete solution but some tips that will allow you to create it.

You need to store all informations in database - it's obvious. Design of the tables is up to you, but let's say you have something like that, table called friendship:

```
UserID INT(10)
FriendID INT(10)
```

Of course you need to take care about relations on your own. So, in our model we have following situation:

- UserA send a request to UserB
- UserB is able to accept or reject request sent by UserA
- When request is accepted you need to store such information in database
- I saw multiple approaches in this case. Everything depends on your database design and your code

Without knowing anything about your app, we're able to tell you nothing. Creating such functionality isn't hard and I'll call it beginner task however it might be confusing for newbies sometimes.

With the tips provided you'll be able to do so without any problems.

Comment: there are questions to be asked. Like is the one way of A -> B considered friendship or it has to be bijective? you will create one entry AB or both AB and BA?

Comment: @Elzo Valugi - There are many techniques. I prefer one entry AB (you can't remeber about foreign keys). Why? I can easily get all friendship relations for both members: A & B. However I recently worked on a system where developers use AB & BA entries. Both solutions seems to be ok for me. Everything depends on your personal taste.